# SVG animation where a paths of crests/waves turns into troughs/valleys with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am trying to get these two similar SVG paths to morph into each other. They are essentially triangles where the sides are waves with crests and troughs. The effect I am trying to accomplish is so that the crests turn into troughs and their neighboring troughs turn into crests as if the waves are moving to the top/far point of the triangle.

I've looked into js libraries to do this and found [Kute.js](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/). It animates the SVG, but not at all what the shapes looking like. It collapses into the top point and then grows out, but never looks like either of the paths. I tried playing with morphPrecision and morphIndex for more quality, but can not seem to get the desired effect and to happen indefinitely/infinitely.

Here are the two paths and the js I am using to animation.

```html
<svg>
    <style type="text/css">
        .yellow{fill:#EEFF41;}
    </style>
    <g id="body">
        <path id="original" class="yellow" d="M140.3,39.3c-0.5-2.2-3.3-9.1-9.7-9.4c-12.4-0.7-11-9.6-14.8-12.2c-6.1-4.1-11.4,0.7-17.1-8.2
        c-3.1-4.8-11-0.1-16.7-4.9c-1.8-1.5-3.9-2.7-5.8-3.5c-1.5-0.6-3.5-1-5.5-1.1c-2,0.1-4,0.5-5.5,1.1c-1.9,0.8-4,2-5.8,3.5
        c-5.7,4.8-13.6,0-16.7,4.9c-5.7,8.9-11,4.1-17.1,8.2c-3.9,2.6-2.4,11.5-14.8,12.2c-6.4,0.4-9.2,7.3-9.7,9.4c-1.4,6.4,3,10.1,3.1,10
        c5.2-6.5,13.1-2.2,22-6.2c3.4-1.5,8.5-6.7,12.3-7.8c6.8-2,14.2,0.7,20.6-1.5c3.9-1.4,7.7-4.3,11.7-4.3c4,0.1,7.8,3,11.7,4.3
        c6.5,2.2,13.9-0.5,20.6,1.5c3.8,1.1,8.9,6.3,12.3,7.8c8.8,4,16.7-0.3,22,6.2C137.3,49.4,141.7,45.7,140.3,39.3z"/>
        <path id="swimming" class="yellow" d="M140.3,38.9c-0.5-2.2-7.4-3.4-9.7-9.4c-4.1-11.1-10.2-12.6-14.8-12.2c-6.1,0.4-12-0.9-17.1-8.2
        C95.4,4.4,88,2.2,82,4.2c-2.4,0.8-5.1,1.3-7.5-1c-1.3-1.3-2.1-1.8-3.8-1.8S68.3,2,66.9,3.2c-2.4,2.3-5.1,1.8-7.5,1
        c-6.1-2-13.4,0.2-16.7,4.9c-5.1,7.3-11,8.6-17.1,8.2C21,17,14.9,18.4,10.8,29.5c-2.2,6-9.2,7.3-9.7,9.4c-1.4,6.4,3,10.1,3.1,10
        c5.2-6.5,13.1-2.2,22-6.2c3.4-1.5,8.5-6.7,12.3-7.8c6.8-2,14.2,0.7,20.6-1.5c3.9-1.3,7.7-4.2,11.6-4.3c4,0.1,7.8,3,11.6,4.3
        c6.5,2.2,13.9-0.5,20.6,1.5c3.8,1.1,8.9,6.3,12.3,7.8c8.8,4,16.7-0.3,22,6.2C137.3,48.9,141.7,45.3,140.3,38.9z" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[Here is Kute.js](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/). The examples make it look easy and I understand that my shapes are more complex, but the paths are very similar, visually.

Here is the line I am calling [Kute.js](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/) with:

```
var tween = KUTE.fromTo('#original', {path: '#original' }, { path: '#swimming' }, {morphPrecision:64, morphIndex:32, repeat:161803}).start();
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the running animation: https://jsfiddle.net/z0ufwxqh/

Is there a better way or a way to achieve this animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem, I think, was that your `morphPrecision` was way too big.

```js
var tween = KUTE.fromTo('#original',
                        {path: '#original' },
                        {path: '#swimming' },
                        {duration: 2500,
                         yoyo: true,
                         repeat:Infinity,
                         morphPrecision:2}).start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/kute.js/1.6.2/kute.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/kute.js/1.6.2/kute-svg.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <g id="body">
        <path id="original" class="yellow" d="M140.3,39.3c-0.5-2.2-3.3-9.1-9.7-9.4c-12.4-0.7-11-9.6-14.8-12.2c-6.1-4.1-11.4,0.7-17.1-8.2
        c-3.1-4.8-11-0.1-16.7-4.9c-1.8-1.5-3.9-2.7-5.8-3.5c-1.5-0.6-3.5-1-5.5-1.1c-2,0.1-4,0.5-5.5,1.1c-1.9,0.8-4,2-5.8,3.5
        c-5.7,4.8-13.6,0-16.7,4.9c-5.7,8.9-11,4.1-17.1,8.2c-3.9,2.6-2.4,11.5-14.8,12.2c-6.4,0.4-9.2,7.3-9.7,9.4c-1.4,6.4,3,10.1,3.1,10
        c5.2-6.5,13.1-2.2,22-6.2c3.4-1.5,8.5-6.7,12.3-7.8c6.8-2,14.2,0.7,20.6-1.5c3.9-1.4,7.7-4.3,11.7-4.3c4,0.1,7.8,3,11.7,4.3
        c6.5,2.2,13.9-0.5,20.6,1.5c3.8,1.1,8.9,6.3,12.3,7.8c8.8,4,16.7-0.3,22,6.2C137.3,49.4,141.7,45.7,140.3,39.3z"/>
        <path id="swimming" class="yellow" d="M140.3,38.9c-0.5-2.2-7.4-3.4-9.7-9.4c-4.1-11.1-10.2-12.6-14.8-12.2c-6.1,0.4-12-0.9-17.1-8.2
        C95.4,4.4,88,2.2,82,4.2c-2.4,0.8-5.1,1.3-7.5-1c-1.3-1.3-2.1-1.8-3.8-1.8S68.3,2,66.9,3.2c-2.4,2.3-5.1,1.8-7.5,1
        c-6.1-2-13.4,0.2-16.7,4.9c-5.1,7.3-11,8.6-17.1,8.2C21,17,14.9,18.4,10.8,29.5c-2.2,6-9.2,7.3-9.7,9.4c-1.4,6.4,3,10.1,3.1,10
        c5.2-6.5,13.1-2.2,22-6.2c3.4-1.5,8.5-6.7,12.3-7.8c6.8-2,14.2,0.7,20.6-1.5c3.9-1.3,7.7-4.2,11.6-4.3c4,0.1,7.8,3,11.6,4.3
        c6.5,2.2,13.9-0.5,20.6,1.5c3.8,1.1,8.9,6.3,12.3,7.8c8.8,4,16.7-0.3,22,6.2C137.3,48.9,141.7,45.3,140.3,38.9z" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I was playing with that and noticed it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You can use css transforms and transitions to achieve this easily. Scaling heigth to 5% can do the trick. I applied these transforms with javascript, as the question requires not to use css.

```js
var path = document.getElementById('original')
var toggle = true
path.style = 'transition: transform 1s;  transform-origin: 50% 20%;'

setInterval(function(){
  path.style.transform = 'scale(1,'+(toggle ? 0.05 : 1)+')';
  toggle = !toggle
},2200)
```

```html
<svg>
    <style type="text/css">
        .yellow{fill:#EEFF41;}
    </style>
    <g id="body">
        <path id="original" class="yellow" d="M140.3,39.3c-0.5-2.2-3.3-9.1-9.7-9.4c-12.4-0.7-11-9.6-14.8-12.2c-6.1-4.1-11.4,0.7-17.1-8.2
        c-3.1-4.8-11-0.1-16.7-4.9c-1.8-1.5-3.9-2.7-5.8-3.5c-1.5-0.6-3.5-1-5.5-1.1c-2,0.1-4,0.5-5.5,1.1c-1.9,0.8-4,2-5.8,3.5
        c-5.7,4.8-13.6,0-16.7,4.9c-5.7,8.9-11,4.1-17.1,8.2c-3.9,2.6-2.4,11.5-14.8,12.2c-6.4,0.4-9.2,7.3-9.7,9.4c-1.4,6.4,3,10.1,3.1,10
        c5.2-6.5,13.1-2.2,22-6.2c3.4-1.5,8.5-6.7,12.3-7.8c6.8-2,14.2,0.7,20.6-1.5c3.9-1.4,7.7-4.3,11.7-4.3c4,0.1,7.8,3,11.7,4.3
        c6.5,2.2,13.9-0.5,20.6,1.5c3.8,1.1,8.9,6.3,12.3,7.8c8.8,4,16.7-0.3,22,6.2C137.3,49.4,141.7,45.7,140.3,39.3z" />
        <path id="swimming" class="yellow" d="M140.3,38.9c-0.5-2.2-7.4-3.4-9.7-9.4c-4.1-11.1-10.2-12.6-14.8-12.2c-6.1,0.4-12-0.9-17.1-8.2
        C95.4,4.4,88,2.2,82,4.2c-2.4,0.8-5.1,1.3-7.5-1c-1.3-1.3-2.1-1.8-3.8-1.8S68.3,2,66.9,3.2c-2.4,2.3-5.1,1.8-7.5,1
        c-6.1-2-13.4,0.2-16.7,4.9c-5.1,7.3-11,8.6-17.1,8.2C21,17,14.9,18.4,10.8,29.5c-2.2,6-9.2,7.3-9.7,9.4c-1.4,6.4,3,10.1,3.1,10
        c5.2-6.5,13.1-2.2,22-6.2c3.4-1.5,8.5-6.7,12.3-7.8c6.8-2,14.2,0.7,20.6-1.5c3.9-1.3,7.7-4.2,11.6-4.3c4,0.1,7.8,3,11.6,4.3
        c6.5,2.2,13.9-0.5,20.6,1.5c3.8,1.1,8.9,6.3,12.3,7.8c8.8,4,16.7-0.3,22,6.2C137.3,48.9,141.7,45.3,140.3,38.9z" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```